Inconsistent Product Names Retrieval in Golang Gin/Gorm Application
I'm encountering an issue with my Golang Gin/Gorm application where the names of certain products retrieved from an external API sometimes appear as null values. The application is designed to fetch product names from an external API endpoint based on product IDs stored in the database.
Here's a brief overview of the application structure:
Gin/Gorm Framework: The application is built using the Gin web framework for HTTP routing and Gorm as the ORM for database operations.
Supply Management: The application manages supplies, each associated with a product stored in the database.
External API Integration: Product names are fetched from an external API endpoint using an HTTP client.

here's the relevant part of the func:
// Convert supplies to supplyResponses
    supplyResponses := make([]models.SupplyResponse, len(supplies))
    apiURLs := make(map[string]string)
    apiURLs["FLOWER"] = os.Getenv("FLOWER_API") + "flower_type/?id="
    apiURLs["SWEET"] = os.Getenv("SWEET_API") + "sweet_type/?id="
    apiURLs["CONSUMABLE"] = os.Getenv("CONSUMABLE_API") + "consumable_type/?id="

    for _, supply := range supplies {
        switch supply.ProductType.Name {
        case "FLOWER":
            apiURLs["FLOWER"] += supply.ProductId.String() + "&id="
        case "SWEET":
            apiURLs["SWEET"] += supply.ProductId.String() + "&id="
        case "CONSUMABLE":
            apiURLs["CONSUMABLE"] += supply.ProductId.String() + "&id="
        default:
            context.IndentedJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "Product type cant be found"})
            return
        }
    }

    for _, url := range apiURLs {
        index := strings.Index(url, "?id=")
        if index != -1 {
            if len(url) > index+len("?id=") {
                lastIndex := strings.LastIndex(url, "&id=")
                if lastIndex != -1 {
                    url = url[:lastIndex]
                }
                names, err := services.GetProductNames(context, url)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err.Error())
                }

                // Loop over each supply and find its corresponding name
                for i, supply := range supplies {
                    supplyResponses[i] = supply.ToSupplyResponse()
                    for _, name := range names.Data {
                        if supply.ProductId == name.Id {
                            switch lang {
                            case "uz":
                                supplyResponses[i].Name = name.Name.Uz
                            case "ru":
                                supplyResponses[i].Name = name.Name.Ru
                            case "en":
                                supplyResponses[i].Name = name.Name.En
                            default:
                                responseNames := models.ProductName{
                                    Uz: name.Name.Uz,
                                    Ru: name.Name.Ru,
                                    En: name.Name.En,
                                }
                                supplyResponses[i].Name = &responseNames
                            }
                            break
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

here's my model:
package models

type Supply struct {
    ID            uuid.UUID      `gorm:"type:uuid;primaryKey;default:gen_random_uuid()"`
    StockID       uuid.UUID      `gorm:"column:stock_id;type:uuid;"`
    SupplyDate    time.Time      `gorm:"column:supply_date;type:timestamp"`
    Quantity      float64        `gorm:"column:quantity;type:double precision"`
    UnitCost      float64        `gorm:"column:unit_cost;type:numeric(10,2)"`
    ProductTypeId uint           `gorm:"column:product_type_id;type:uint;"`
    ProductId     uuid.UUID      `gorm:"column:product_id;type:uuid"`
    Description   string         `gorm:"column:description;type:text"`
    CreatedAt     time.Time      `gorm:"column:created_at"`
    UpdatedAt     time.Time      `gorm:"column:updated_at"`
    DeletedAt     gorm.DeletedAt `gorm:"column:deleted_at"`

    // StockID column relation with Stock model
    Stock       Stock       `gorm:"foreignKey:StockID" json:"stock"`
    ProductType ProductType `gorm:"foreignKey:ProductTypeId" json:"product_type"`
}

// BeforeCreate hook to generate UUID for ID field and set time formats
func (supply *Supply) BeforeCreate(tx *gorm.DB) (err error) {
    supply.ID = uuid.New()
    return nil
}

type SupplyResponse struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID           `json:"id"`
    StockID     uuid.UUID           `json:"stockId"`
    SupplyDate  string              `json:"supplyDate"`
    Quantity    float64             `json:"quantity"`
    UnitCost    float64             `json:"unitCost"`
    ProductType ProductTypeResponse `json:"productType"`
    ProductId   uuid.UUID           `json:"productId"`
    Description string              `json:"description"`
    CreatedAt   string              `json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt   string              `json:"updatedAt"`
    DeletedAt   string              `json:"deletedAt"`
    Stock       StockResponse       `json:"stock"`
    Name        interface{}         `json:"name"`
}

func FormatStock(stock Stock) StockResponse {
    deletedAt := ""
    if stock.DeletedAt.Valid {
        deletedAt = stock.DeletedAt.Time.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05")
    }

    return StockResponse{
        ID:         stock.ID,
        MerchantID: stock.MerchantID,
        BranchID:   stock.BranchID,
        CreatedAt:  stock.CreatedAt.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"),
        UpdatedAt:  stock.UpdatedAt.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"),
        DeletedAt:  deletedAt,
    }
}

func (supply *Supply) ToSupplyResponse() SupplyResponse {
    deletedAt := ""
    if supply.DeletedAt.Valid {
        deletedAt = supply.DeletedAt.Time.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05")
    }

    // Retrieve the ProductType struct from the database
    var productType ProductType
    if err := initializers.DB.First(&productType, supply.ProductTypeId).Error; err != nil {
        // Handle error if the ProductType is not found
        return SupplyResponse{}
    }

    return SupplyResponse{
        ID:          supply.ID,
        StockID:     supply.StockID,
        SupplyDate:  supply.SupplyDate.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"),
        Quantity:    supply.Quantity,
        UnitCost:    supply.UnitCost,
        ProductType: productType.ToProductTypeResponse(),
        ProductId:   supply.ProductId,
        Description: supply.Description,
        CreatedAt:   supply.CreatedAt.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"),
        UpdatedAt:   supply.UpdatedAt.Format("2006-01-02T15:04:05"),
        DeletedAt:   deletedAt,
        Stock:       FormatStock(supply.Stock),
    }
}

type IdentifySupplyResponse struct {
    QuantityTaken float64        `json:"quantityTaken"`
    Supply        SupplyResponse `json:"supply"`
}

type ProductNames struct {
    Data []struct {
        Id   uuid.UUID `json:"id"`
        Name struct {
            Uz string `json:"uz"`
            Ru string `json:"ru"`
            En string `json:"en"`
        } `json:"name"`
    } `json:"data"`
}

type ProductName struct {
    Uz string `json:"uz"`
    Ru string `json:"ru"`
    En string `json:"en"`
}


and getProductNames func:
func GetProductNames(context *gin.Context, url string) (models.ProductNames, error) {
    _, _, err := middlewares.CheckPermissions(context)
    if err != nil {
        context.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"error": err.Error()})
        return models.ProductNames{}, err
    }

    authToken := context.GetHeader("Authorization")

    request, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        return models.ProductNames{}, err
    }

    fmt.Println(url)

    request.Header.Set("Authorization", authToken)

    response, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(request)
    if err != nil {
        return models.ProductNames{}, err
    }
    defer response.Body.Close()

    if response.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return models.ProductNames{}, fmt.Errorf("unexpected status code: %d", response.StatusCode)
    }

    var responseData models.ProductNames

    err = json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&responseData)
    if err != nil {
        return models.ProductNames{}, fmt.Errorf("error decoding data: %v", err.Error())
    }

    fmt.Println(responseData)

    return responseData, nil
}

it is working on local perfectly, but on the production where it is dockerized app, the issue is happening
